# C# "Out Of Memory Exception" on returning variable accessor

Tags: c#, bitmap, garbage-collection, computer-vision

I am getting an Out Of Memory Exception when I attempt to new a Bitmap and return it through a "get" accessor.  The Bitmap is of size 640x480 with depth Int32.

My suspicion is that the C# Garbage Collector is unable to delete these old Bitmaps because they are being returned in the accessor to my variable.  I have well over 2GB available so I wouldn't imagine that this "small" image is taking up too much memory.  Unfortunately I HAVE to new the Bitmap due to thread locking issues ([Trouble with locking an image between threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596429/trouble-with-locking-an-image-between-threads))  The code is as follows:

```
public Bitmap LiveFrame { get { return GetFrame(500); } }
```

.....

```
private Bitmap GetFrame(int timeout)
{
   Bitmap ret = null;
   //CLEyeCameraGetFrame places image data into this._PrivateBitmap
   bool success = CLEyeCameraGetFrame(_Camera, _PtrBmpPixels, timeout);  

   if(success) 
     ret = new Bitmap(this._PrivateBitmap);
    return ret;
}
```

Note on unmanaged code:
CLEyeCameraGetFrame is in an unmanaged DLL.  I allocate _PtrBmpPixels using Marshal.AllocHGlobal earlier in the code and don't touch it until freeing when closing the app.  _PtrBmpPixels was used in the creation of the Bitmap _PrivateBitmap through its constructor that accepts the IntPtr argument "scan0".  Thus, whenever _PtrBmpPixels is updated via CLEyeCameraGetFrame, _PrivateBitmap is also updated.

I attempted to fix this by Disposing the PcitureBox Bitmap before reusing it, but that broke the PictureBox display.  I have two threads updating two different PictureBox/ImageBoxes:

```
lock (_CameraLocker)
{
  if (_VideoPlaying)
  {
    try{
         if (pbLiveFeed.Image != null)
            pbLiveFeed.Image.Dispose();

         pbLiveFeed.Image = _Camera.LiveFrame;
         pbLiveFeed.Invalidate();
       }catch (Exception ex) { }
}
```

....

```
lock (_CameraLocker)
{
   try{
        if (ibProcessed.Image != null)
          ibProcessed.Image.Dispose();
        procImage = new Image<Bgra, Int32>(_Camera.LiveFrame);
        procImage.Draw(new Rectangle(10, 20, 20, 15), new Bgra(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0), 5);

        ibProcessed.Image = procImage;
      }catch (Exception ex) { }
}
```

Could Garbage collection be the cause of this?  Is it not safe to return a newed object from a get accessor?

Comment: That should be perfectly safe to do. It's possible that the underlying native GDI code is throwing an exception on the native side that gets converted into a (bogus) out-of-memory exception on the managed side. Are you platform invoking out to a scanner, or similar?

Comment: Side note: consider not using property for something that is expected to take relatively long time - use method instead. Also it looks like you can't us this property as property (i.e. `item.LiveFrame.Width` have side effect of creating "huge" object that will be thrown away immediately).

Comment: Yes actually I am.  That Bitmap gets used to create other objects which are then used in unmanaged code.  Because I new the object that is used in unmanaged code I would think that the bitmap data is simply copied over and is not put into the unmanaged code itself.

Comment: What are you doing with these `Bitmap` instances once they are created?

Comment: Paul: I am assigning them to PictureBox.Image or I am creating an Emgu.CV.Image object with them.
And thank you, Alexei, for pointing that out.  It is an obvious misuse of a property and I missed noticing that.
I am still curios as to why this is happening though.

Comment: From what you have said above, it sounds as though you are allocating memory in unmanaged code but not subsequently deleting (freeing) it.

Comment: Paul: That would be a problem IN the unmanaged code then right?  I only pass managed objects (already allocated) to the unmanaged functions so the Garbage Collector should take care of them, correct?

Comment: According to the comment in the code, `CLEyeCameraGetFrame` is a function that is creating an image and putting it into `_PrivateBitmap`. Is this function managed or unmanaged? Could you provide its code?

Comment: Yes it is unmanaged.  I would assuming that it it doesn't do any allocing/freeing because it needs a IntPtr that is already allocated.  (I allocate _PtrBmpPixels earlier using Marshal.AllocHGlobal)  Though I am looking for the code now in case it is leaking memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only real clue in your question is in what is *missing*.  You never said "and I make sure to dispose the bitmap after using it".  Which is something you can overlook easily in .NET programming but will come to byte you when you use bitmaps.

The Bitmap class is a very small wrapper class around an *unmanaged* resource created by GDI+.  The actual bitmap pixels are stored in unmanaged memory.  Which is why the class has a Dispose() method, that releases the unmanaged memory allocation.  The garbage collector can do little to help you get this memory released automatically, a Bitmap object is too small to induce a garbage collection often enough to keep up with the rate at which your program consumes unmanaged memory.  An oom-kaboom is the outcome.

You'll need to look at the rest of your code and see how the LiveFrame property is getting used.  And make sure that the returned bitmap is getting disposed.  If, say, you assign it to a PictureBox.Image property then you have to dispose the old image before assigning it.

Comment: +1 Sounds like a good moment to pull out your [Design Patterns](http://www.amazon.com/Design-Patterns-Elements-Reusable-Object-Oriented/dp/0201633612) book and rethink things a bit.

Comment: Ah that sounds about right.  I am not disposing it anywhere so I imagine constant newing would definitely cause this problem.  I will update this once I check it.

Comment: Well, the only times I use the Bitmap are to assign them to a PictureBox and to an EMGU ImageBox.  I have updated teh main post with the code showing how I tried to Dispose the Bitmap.  When I do this however it breaks the display and just shows a big red X in the pictureBox.

Comment: I don't see an update.  Dispose the old one just before the assign the new one so you won't crash the painting code.  The crash produces the red cross.

Comment: Sorry, updated now.  Should have updated before saying that I had updated, whoops.

Comment: Could you be more specific?  My program uses more than 2 threads, yes.  But the two threads reading from the camera are not accessing the same Bitmap.  As you can see in my accessor code the Bitmap is newed before being returned by the "get".  It never access violates or gives errors about incorrect locking.

Comment: Well, I changed the class to not return the Bitamp through an accessor but through the function GetFrame() (as I should have from the beginning) and now using Dispose as you suggested works just fine.  Unless something else weird crops up then I think I am set.